# Regex/Python noob needs assistence

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to pull a specific recurring item from emails using regex and python, 
the pattern is always:

```
OS - TYPE - VER - en - he_IL - 1.1.2 - U: username - hash
```

i was trying to do it with the following condition:

```
if re.search('U: \s*( - )', message_body)
```

hoping to get "username" out, unfortunately it didn't give out anything.

also, trying `if re.search('U: \w*())', message_body)` gave me response that was too broad and included the actual "U: " with the username.

i would love to get some pointers that does not include link to the manual.

Comment: is the string always identical before username?

Comment: Are there specific naming rules for username? I.e. do special characters appear in the usernames?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, it's *always* like that as it's computer generated.

Comment: @R.L. Numbers and letters only, but as it's computer generated i assume i can always trust it (although you raise a valid point regarding normalization of the input just in case)

Comment: Thank you everyone ! i'm not allowed to upvote yet but you've all helped.

Comment: Well, no one cared to explain, so here goes: your current expression matches `U:` then a space, then any number of `\s` (spaces, newlines and various other line breaks) and then captures space, dash, space. This expression would only match `U:` followed by at least 2 spaces, a dash and then a space. Your second expression matches `U:`, a space and any `\w` characters, then captures an empty string with `()`. You could have instead put the paren around the `\w*` and then use `.group()` to get the username.

Comment: @Jerry Pure gold, it's actually more important then the solution itself - thank you for taking the time.

Comment: @Amit No prob, my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a capture group with an actual expression:

```
match = re.search('U:\s*(\S+)')
if match: username = match.group(1)

match = re.search('U:\s*(\S+ - \S+)')
if match: username_and_hash = match.group(1)

match = re.search('U:\s*(\S+) - (\S+)')
if match:
    username = match.group(1)
    userhash = match.group(2)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer i was looking for.

Comment: Any chance you can help me with the exception that username is N/A ? (there are such cases, then the rule takes "N/A"), i'm referring to cases like `OS - TYPE - VER - en - he_IL - 1.1.2 - U: N/A - hash`

Comment: What do you want the result to be when the username is N/A? Probably the most straight forward way to deal with it, is checking the value of the username, e.g. `if username == 'N/A'` then whatever you need to do in that case.

Comment: Is there any way to return the If statement as false in this case ?

Comment: well, you could use a negative lookahead: `re.search('U:\s*((?!N/A)\S+)')` which matches any username which does not start 'N/A'.

Answer (score 1):

```
U:\s*(\S+)
```

Try this.Use `print re.search(r"U:\s*(\S+)",x).group(1)` to get  `username`.

Here `x` is your string.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/73

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split`:

```
s = "OS - TYPE - VER - en - he_IL - 1.1.2 - U: username - hash"
print (s.split("U: ")[1].split()[0])
username
```

Or using re:

```
import re
(re.findall(" U:\s+(\w+)",s)[0])
username
```

re is considerably slower:

```
In [20]: timeit (re.findall(" U:\s+(\w+)",s)[0])
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.5 µs per loop

In [21]: timeit (s.split("U: ")[1].split()[0])

1000000 loops, best of 3: 764 ns per loop
```

Comment: this *does* work, but uses a different method then i was looking for, thanks anyway.

Comment: @Amit, it is a lot more efficient than your accepted answer